# MongoDB Prometheus-Community exporter not able to fetch the metrics of MongoDB which is enabled by TLS

Tags: mongodb, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

Using Prometheus-community Exporter for fetching metrics from MongoDB Which is TLS enabled. but metrics are not showing in the Prometheus and in logs of Exporter pod as:

kubectl  logs expo-prometheus-mongodb-exporter-55865c7f86-kvg4r -n final-test

time="2022-03-15T11:25:27Z" level=info msg="Starting mongodb_exporter (version=, branch=, revision=)" source="mongodb_exporter.go:94"
time="2022-03-15T11:25:27Z" level=info msg="Build context (go=go1.11.13, user=, date=19700101-00:00:00)" source="mongodb_exporter.go:95"
time="2022-03-15T11:25:27Z" level=error msg="(CommandNotSupportedOnView) Namespace local.system.tenantMigration.oplogView is a view, not a collection. Collection stats will not be collected for this collection. This log message will be suppressed from now." source="collections_status.go:169"
time="2022-03-15T11:25:27Z" level=error msg="(Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command { aggregate: "system.version", pipeline: [ { $indexStats: {} } ], cursor: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("8224906c-49b8-4699-8b3a-972d5518caa0") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1647343521, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, F43E74F913B4AECCA2BC772062CFA55B067693D8), keyId: 7073820031389270020 } }, $db: "admin", $readPreference: { mode: "nearest" } }. Index usage stats will not be collected for this collection. This log message will be suppressed from now." source="index_usage.go:104"
time="2022-03-15T11:25:27Z" level=error msg="(Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command { aggregate: "system.keys", pipeline: [ { $indexStats: {} } ], cursor: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("8224906c-49b8-4699-8b3a-972d5518caa0") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1647343521, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, F43E74F913B4AECCA2BC772062CFA55B067693D8), keyId: 7073820031389270020 } }, $db: "admin", $readPreference: { mode: "nearest" } }. Index usage stats will not be collected for this collection. This log message will be suppressed from now." source="index_usage.go:104"
time="2022-03-15T11:25:27Z" level=error msg="(Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command { aggregate: "system.users", pipeline: [ { $indexStats: {} } ], cursor: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("8224906c-49b8-4699-8b3a-972d5518caa0") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1647343521, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, F43E74F913B4AECCA2BC772062CFA55B067693D8), keyId: 7073820031389270020 } }, $db: "admin", $readPreference: { mode: "nearest" } }. Index usage stats will not be collected for this collection. This log message will be suppressed from now." source="index_usage.go:104"
time="2022-03-15T11:25:27Z" level=error msg="(Unauthorized) not authorized on config to execute command { aggregate: "system.indexBuilds", pipeline: [ { $indexStats: {} } ], cursor: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("8224906c-49b8-4699-8b3a-972d5518caa0") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1647343521, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, F43E74F913B4AECCA2BC772062CFA55B067693D8), keyId: 7073820031389270020 } }, $db: "config", $readPreference: { mode: "nearest" } }. Index usage stats will not be collected for this collection. This log message will be suppressed from now." source="index_usage.go:104"
time="2022-03-15T11:25:27Z" level=error msg="(Unauthorized) not authorized on config to execute command { aggregate: "system.sessions", pipeline: [ { $indexStats: {} } ], cursor: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("8224906c-49b8-4699-8b3a-972d5518caa0") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1647343521, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, F43E74F913B4AECCA2BC772062CFA55B067693D8), keyId: 7073820031389270020 } }, $db: "config", $readPreference: { mode: "nearest" } }. Index usage stats will not be collected for this collection. This log message will be suppressed from now." source="index_usage.go:104"
time="2022-03-15T11:25:27Z" level=error msg="(Unauthorized) not authorized on local to execute command { aggregate: "replset.minvalid", pipeline: [ { $indexStats: {} } ], cursor: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("8224906c-49b8-4699-8b3a-972d5518caa0") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1647343521, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, F43E74F913B4AECCA2BC772062CFA55B067693D8), keyId: 7073820031389270020 } }, $db: "local", $readPreference: { mode: "nearest" } }. Index usage stats will not be collected for this collection. This log message will be suppressed from now." source="index_usage.go:104"
[ { $indexStats: {} } ], cursor: {}, lsid: { id: UUID("8224906c-49b8-4699-8b3a-972d5518caa0") }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: Timestamp(1647343521, 1), signature: { hash: BinData(0, F43E74F913B4AECCA2BC772062CFA55B067693D8), keyId: 7073820031389270020 } }, $db: "local", $readPreference: { mode: "nearest" } }. Index usage stats will not be collected for this collection. This log message will be suppressed from now." source="index_usage.go:104"
time="2022-03-15T11:25:27Z" level=info msg="Starting HTTP server for http://:9216/metrics ..." source="server.go:140"

MongoDB is Enabled by TLS
Connection string is:
"mongodb://mongo:mongo123@mongodb-2.mongodb.final-test.svc.cluster.local:27017/admin?replicaSet=rs1&tls=true&tlsCertificateKeyFile=/tmp/tls-combined.pem&tlsCAFile=/tmp/ca.crt"

Any Suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this issue with a mongodb-exporter deployed through bitnami's helm chart where in order to get mongodb metrics besides mongodb_up was to provide "--collect-all" flag to exporter. If you are using the same chart then you need to provide it through extraFlags in the values.yaml

```yaml
extraFlags: "--collect-all"
```

if the exporter is spinned-up via compose then you will need to have it under command such as (it will obviously be different considering that you will tls flags in there):

```yaml
    command: 
      - "--mongodb.uri=mongodb://mongo:27017"
      - "--mongodb.collstats-colls=Test.Listings"
      - "--discovering-mode"
      - "--mongodb.direct-connect"  
      - "--collect-all"
```

The image being used within our chart was "bitnami/mongodb-exporter:0.32.0-debian-10-r3".

However, the available dashboards make use of older metric names so my dashboards that I picked from under percona's repository even after modifying the datasources did not get populated.

One suggestion regarding when I was searching online was that is adding "--compatible-mode" as well but that has been reported to be not working with mongo:5 and up. I have yet to confirm with previous releases such as mongo:4.2

I am currently trying to convert the queries of the dashboards accordingly with the new metric names though it ain't pretty.

Hope this helps.